# How to get moodle module name from module id

Tags: moodle

I want to list the names of the modules (activities) in my course sections from moodle function or from db query.

I can get section details and module id from `mdl_course_sections`  and `mdl_course_modules` tables I want to get name or tile put in every activity to be list down.

I already tried `mod_frog_get_coursemodule_info($cm)` but I hadn't any luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this with following code

```
$activity_modules = $DB->get_record('modules',array('id' =>$moduleid));
$dynamic_activity_modules_data = $DB->get_record($activity_modules->name,array('id' =>$instanceid));
echo $dynamic_activity_modules_data->name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_fast_mod_info()` e.g.:

```
$modinfo = get_fast_modinfo($courseid);
foreach ($modinfo as $cm) {
    echo $cm->modname;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I advise you :

```
$modinfo = get_fast_modinfo($courseid);
$cm = $modinfo->get_cm($moduleid);
```

**Reference:** https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Module_visibility_and_display#get_fast_modinfo_data

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_fast_modinfo()` :

```
$cm = $modinfo->cms[$moduleid];

$modulename = $cm->modname;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in 2 lines within moodle structure:

```
global $DB;
$moduleName = $DB->get_field('modules','name',array('id' => $moduleID));
```